# Creating Android manifest xml by pure AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, namespaces, android-manifest, prefix

Can some one create this manifest xml using only Action Script code? I want to make an application that creates manifest files but i got problem on prefixes and namespaces:

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Very simple sample Action Script code to generate:

```
main = new XML(<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto"/>);
main.appendChild(<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />)
```

Cause:

```
TypeError: Error #1083: The prefix "android" for element "minSdkVersion" is not bound.
```

I don't know how to set prefixes for XML files.

Comment: The **new XML(...)** constructor takes a **String** as an argument, while you are passing an **XML** object.

Comment: Action Script supports JSX to. but I changed the code to make you sure:
main = new XML('<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto"/>');
   main.appendChild(new XML('<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />')).

Same error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I poked it around a bit and that's what I've figured.

This works:

```
var M:XML =

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>;
```

This doesn't:

```
var M:XML;

M = <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" />;
M.appendChild(<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />);
```

I am no big XML expert, but I guess it is because of the following. We can translate the last piece of code as:

```
var U:XML = <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />;
var M:XML = <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" />;

M.appendChild(U);
```

I explicitly put **U** before **M**, because the order does not matter here, but this way it's kind of self-explanatory.

If you look at it this way, you'll clearly see that **android** prefix exists in **M** only and never existed in **U**. Flash Player doesn't have a precognition module and has no idea you intend **U** only as a part of **M**. Then, as a separate **XML** instance, **U**, as you are trying to create it, is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to do something about prefixes. because I'm going to develop a dynamic XML generator and I should change the minSdk and others by a function.

Comment: @MESepehr You can construct all nodes as **String**s then create **new XML(...)** as a whole. Or you can create the whole XML at once first, then work with its attributes.